# What is nsswitch compat mode?

Tags: redhat, ldap, pam, pam-ldap, nsswitch.conf

Red Hat recommended me compat mode in /etc/nsswitch.conf as one of the options to enumerate LDAP users, but later said that it's not a much-used method.

```
nsswitch.conf
passwd: files compat
passwd_compat: ldap

in passwd file, add +@netgroup.
```

What is this compat mode?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This excerpt was taken from amazing book written by Linux advocate Evi Nemeth( unfortunately recently lost in the sea http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/07/05/evi_nemeth_unix_dead/ )  in her one of the first and best linux admin book: Linux® Administration Handbook. For this case it was in the second edition of the book, I am not sure if this was duplicated in the latest 4th edition of the book, as by that time is NIS and NIS+ is less relevant.

> Configuration information can be distributed in several ways. Every
>   system understands flat files and knows how to use DNS to look up
>   hostnames and Internet addresses. Most also understand NIS. Since a
>   given piece of information could come from several potential sources,
>   Linux provides a way for you to specify the sources that are to be
>   checked and the order in which the checks are made.
>
> In the original (pre-Linux) implementation of NIS, some configuration
>   files (the /etc/passwd and /etc/group files in particular) had to be
>   configured to “invite in” the contents of the corresponding NIS maps.
>   The invitation was extended by inclusion of special incantations in
>   the files themselves. A lone “+” at the beginning of a line would
>   include the entire NIS map, “+@netgroup” would include only entries
>   relevant to a given netgroup, and “+name” would include a single
>   entry.
>
> This approach was never very well liked, and it has been superseded by
>   a central config file, /etc/nsswitch.conf, that allows an explicit
>   search path to be specified for each type of administrative
>   information. The original behavior can be emulated by use of a
>   compatibility mode, but it’s unlikely you would want to use this
>   feature on a newly configured network. (Unfortunately, emulation is
>   most distributions’ default.)
>
> The common sources are nis, nisplus, files, dns, and compat; they
>   refer to NIS, NIS+,[5] vanilla flat files (ignoring tokens such as
>   “+”), DNS, and NISified flat files (honoring “+”), respectively.